# .htaccess redirect php to html and also I want add language flag except to English

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

Rules above is to replace .php to .html. Recently I added a another language for the site.
The site now running Chinese language when /?lang=hi exists in the browser address bar.

It's kinda ugly from the example below:
- http://www.example.com/?lang=hi
- http://www.example.com/about-us.html?lang=hi
- http://www.example.com/contact-us.html?lang=hi

Example
What I want is Index of Hindhi
- http://www.example.com/?lang=hi equals to http://www.example.com/hi
- http://www.example.com/about-us.html?lang=hi equals to http://www.example.com/hi/about-us.html
- http://www.example.com/contact-us.html?lang=hi equals to http://www.example.com/hi/contact-us.html

http://www.example.com/ will not redirect to http://www.example.com/en
- English site will remain as http://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com/ equals to http://www.example.com/
- http://www.example.com/?lang=en equals to http://www.example.com/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} =-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php? [QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This is your answer I think : https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54320/htaccess-language-redirects-with-seo-friendly-urls

Comment: @Dilek It's not working , I followed above url. I think I need to change something because above code of .htaccess using on vanilla php framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules :

```
RewriteEngine on

##############################
#Redirect php to html
#This will redirect and rewrite your php files to html
#redirect file.php to file.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule .+ /%1.html [L,R,NE]
#Rewrite file.html to file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.html$
RewriteCond %1.php  -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1.php [L]
#############################
#language redirection
#1) /?lang=hi as /hi (for hompage)
RewriteRule ^hi/?$ /?lang=hi [L,NC]
#for html pages
RewriteRule ^hi/(.+)\.html$ /$1.html?lang=hi [L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing these rules.

When you are happy with the rules Change R to R=301 to make the redirection permanent and browser cached.